# Как сделать чтобы по нажатию на ссылку пользователь перенаправлся на нужную ссылку

Tags: html, css, django

я создаю кнопку обсуждения но после нажатия пользователя перенаправляет на http://localhost:8000/news/1/discussion/ а должно на http://localhost:8000/discussion/
Прошу заметить что "1" в адресе это адрес страницы и он может быть и 2 и 3231 любым числом так что решение в роде path('news/1/discussion/') не подойдет

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[

    path('discussion/', views.GetComments,name='discussion')

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html шаблон

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class=" text-info">{{object.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p> {{object.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
        <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликовано: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
    </div>

        <h4>Comments</h4>


     <h1> <a href="discussion/"> Обсуждения </a> </h1>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как вы работаете с Django, вам следует использовать стандартный шаблонный тег url

```
<a href="{% url 'discussion' %}">Обсуждения</a>
```

[В документации все хорошо разъясняется, что, как, зачем и почему. Советую почитать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

Answer (score 1):

Замените относительную ссылку на абсолютную:

```html
<a href="/discussion/">
```