# Как выводить теги в шаблон (django-taggit)

Tags: html, python, django

Я уже добавил теги (django-taggit) и теперь мне нужно их как нибудь вывести в шаблон, и я не знаю нужно ли создавать функцию во views для этого. И еще нужно ли добавлять что либо в urls.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

posts.html шаблон

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in object_list  %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="{% url 'article_detail' article.pk %}"> <h1> {{article.title}} </h1> </a>
          <h3 align="right">{{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Конечно, нужно. Получаете объект тегов, добавляете его в контекст рендеринга и рендерите с ним шаблон. В шаблоне указываете что-то наподобие `{{ tags }}`, зависит от того, как Вы назовёте его в контексте.

Comment: Эммм можешь скинуть поподробнее или где об этом можно прочитать все облазал только было но со старым django где url писали а не path и я вобще хз как с этого бурятского переводить как вот этот код  применить в django новом url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$

Comment: Это базовые вещи, для них вполне подойдут и старые курсы\документация. Вам потребуется менять `url` на `path`, но это единственное значимое отличие, которое я заметил поначалу. Если уж на то пошло, то можете переводить не с бурятского, а с английского (+9 других языков) [официальную документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/)

Comment: Для того, чтобы применить код из 2 комментария, Вам понадобится `re_path`.

Comment: А причём здесь теги? Теги в отдельном файле создаются, регистрируются, отрисовываются в отдельном шаблоне и потом подключаются... Чет не видно у вас тегов.

Comment: или речь о встроенных тегах? Тогда вот `{% <tag> <condition> %}` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы ходите вывести все теги, то они уже доступны в объекты, к которому из привязывали в качестве менеджера. А это значит вы можете их получить, вызвав метод all():

```
{% for tag in article.tags.all %}
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Если вам нужны конкретные, например только те, что содержат какое-либо слово, то нужно будет передать в контекст отфильтрованный queryset тегов, либо в модели Articket определить метод, который вернет этот отфильтрованный queryset

Что касается ссылок, то внимание на [один из ваших прошлых вопросов, где я вам оставлял ссылочку на документацию про url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998235/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB/998294#998294)